# merging master and child tables

Tags: sql

Folks. I have 2 tables, one is tblMaster other is tblChild.  I need to pull each row from master and combine it with all the rows from child. what is the SQL?
Example:

```
tblMaster 
1
2
3
4

tblChild
.1
.3
.7
.9
```

shoud be

```
1.1
1.3
1.7
1.9
2.1
2.3
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 3):

That's just a `CROSS JOIN`, aka [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Basically it joins all rows on the left to all rows on the right to give you all possible combinations of values:

```
SELECT cola + colb
FROM tblMaster
CROSS JOIN tblChild
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tblMaster.column || tblChild.column 
FROM tblMaster, tblChild
```

`||` does string concatenation in Oracle and Postgres. I think SQL Server uses `+`. Not sure about MySQL.

Comment: I see that now, thanks - wasn't in the original question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MasterID + ChildID Combined
FROM   tblMaster M
       FULL OUTER JOIN tblChild C
         ON 1 = 1
```